# Resources with information on rewrite rules with NGINX

Tags: apache, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to understand how to use rewrite rules in NGINX. In Apache I use this:

```
RewriteEngine On                                                        
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$                      
RewriteRule / http://localhost:3000/?alias=%1&theme=%1 [P]
```

and I would like understand how to do the same in NGINX.

Does anyone know any good resource to help me with NGINX and rewrite rules with query strings?

I tried:

```
rewrite ^/?id=(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/?alias=%1&theme=%1 last;
```

but it didn't seem to work. I'm sure it's but I need more information to help me understand it.

In Apache I also set [P] to proxy the request. Is there something similar with NGINX when rewriting the URL?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot capture the query string with `rewrite`, but you could use `$arg_id` as a substitute for the value of the parameter.

Comment: I’ll look into that, thanks.

Comment: Yep looks like that’s the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard Smith correctly pointed out, I can use $arg_id

```
if ($args ~* "/?id=") {                                            
    rewrite ^ /?alias=$arg_id&theme=$arg_id? break;     
}
```

Seems to work exactly how I want it to.

Thanks